# Different module on same set

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a (left) $R$-module. Is there any example that $M$ has two $R$-module structure? (i.e. has different $R$-multiplications)

Comment: You can always define $rm=0$ for all $r \in R$ and $m \in M$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Equivalent definition of $R$ module structure on group $A$ is a ring homomorphism from R$\rightarrow End_{Ab}(A)$. In this language different $R$ module structures on abelian group are defined by different homomorphisms. For example take Regular $\mathbb Z$ module $\mathbb Z_\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Z$ with $0$ multiplication. Those are of course different. It's easy to see that $End_{Ab}(\mathbb Z)\cong \mathbb Z$ in this case first structure corresponds to morphism $id_\mathbb Z$ and second to $0_\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Since modules are often implicitly assumed to be unital, i.e. $1m=m$ for all $m\in M$, let me provide an example under this assumption. Take $R=\mathbb{R}[X]$. Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $\mathbb{R}$ is an $R$-module by defining $Xv=av$ for all $v\in \mathbb{R}$. So in this case you even have infinitely many module structures on the same set.